# Oracle PL/SQL network requests parallelizing

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL script which fetch some XML data via HTTP using SYS.UTL_HTTP. 
But network is slow.
I would open up to 5-10 simultaneous HTTP connections, fetch 5-10 pages and process it.
How can I parallelize these network requests in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option would likely be to spawn multiple database jobs and have each one make a subset of the calls.  Depending on the Oracle version, you can either use the `DBMS_JOB` or the `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package to spawn your own jobs to do this, i.e.

```
FOR x IN (SELECT url_to_access FROM table_of_urls)
LOOP
  dbms_job.submit( l_jobid,
                   'BEGIN procedure_to_access_url(' || x.url_to_access || '); END;' );
END LOOP;
```

If you are on 11.2, however, Oracle has provided a framework to have the database automatically allocate work to a number of `DBMS_SCHEDULER` jobs using the [`DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE` package](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbms_parallel_execute_11gR2.php).

Answer (score 0):

A single PL/SQL can't readily spawn threads. What you can do is have multiple variables of utl_http.req. Then you

```
v_req1 := utl_http.begin_request('http....');
v_req2 := utl_http.begin_request('http....');
v_req3 := utl_http.begin_request('http....');
v_req4 := utl_http.begin_request('http....');
v_resp := utl_http.get_response(v_req1);
...
v_resp := utl_http.get_response(v_req2);
...
v_resp := utl_http.get_response(v_req3);
...
v_resp := utl_http.get_response(v_req4);
...
```

Whether that actually works faster depends on the server at the other end. It can be a pain to handle errors in this scenario though.